# What exactly do we mean when we say "gluing along"?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I've heard this "gluing along" terminology in the context of algebraic geometry and always felt like I could understand it in context, however when I start to think about what it means precisely, I find myself lost. What do we mean when we say things like "gluing along open sets" or "gluing schemes along open subschemes" or "gluing along the identity isomorphism $id:\mathbb{C}^*\rightarrow\mathbb{C}^*$ produces the affine line with doubled origin”?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gluing_schemes

Comment: The general English use of the term "gluing along", as seen commonly in constructing model airplanes, for example, translates into mathematics to say that to glue sets $X$ to $Y$ along some subset $X_0$ of $X$ and some subset $Y_0$ of $Y$ means that we use a bijection of $X_0$ to $Y_0$, usually an obvious one which remains implicitly understood, and take the obvious quotient identifying the bijectively matched points.

Comment: Typically this is a case of categorical colimit, e.g., cofiber coproduct.